# Listing entries of a remotely stored ZIP archive

Tags: node.js, zip

Is there a way in Node.js - using standard modules or 3rd party modules - to list entries of a ZIP archive using just a subset of the compressed data?

I have a collection of potentially large ZIP archives in a cloud data management system (which allows me to request subsets of each file's contents using the `Range` HTTP header), and I would like to list their entries without downloading and parsing the entire file.